# SQL Server join two columns both ID of a table with another table's primary Key Column

Tags: sql-server, join

I was wondering if there is an easy way of joining these two tables.

**Table1**

```
Name FromCountryID ToCountryID
------------------------------
sam         1          2    
lee         3          4
john        2          1
```

**Table2**:

```
CountryID   CountryName
1           USA
2           UK
3           Canada
4           Nepal
```

Comment: Yes, as the simplest of tutorials would make clear.

Comment: @Sandeep Maharajan : Can you just clear the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining multiple tables in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987321/joining-multiple-tables-in-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the same table twice with different alias names

```
select t1.name, 
       fromTab.countryName as FromCountry,
       toTab.countryName as ToCountry
from table1 t1
left join table2 fromTab on fromTab.countryId = t1.fromCountryId
left join table2 toTab on toTab.countryId = t1.toCountryId
```

Comment: If just in case  FromCountryID or ToCountryID might be null.what would be the correct Query???

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.CountryID = Table1.FromCountryID
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.Maybe my question was not that clear but @juergen answer was correct in my case.