# Query linking 4 tables with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following 4 tables:

student_info:

```
S_ID naam   email   telefoon locatie U_ID
   1 Walter Walter@ 03938    Home       1
```

student_combi:

```
S_ID V_ID
   1    1
```

student_vak:

```
V_ID vak  R_ID
   1 HTML    1
```

student_richting:

R_ID richting
      1 Web-Development

I would like the query to SELECT 'vak' (from the 'student_vak' table) and 'richting' (from the 'student_richting' table) using INNER JOIN

So far I have this:

```
SELECT student_vak.vak,student_richting.richting
FROM student_vak
INNER JOIN student_richting ON student_vak.R_ID = student_richting.R_ID
INNER JOIN student_combi ON student_info.S_ID = student_combi.S_ID
INNER JOIN student_vak ON student_combi.V_ID = student_vak.V_ID
INNER JOIN student_richting ON student_vak.R_ID = student_richting.R_ID
```

Thank you in advance if you know the answer.

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output

Comment: Sample data inside student_vak: V_ID=1, vak=HTML, R_ID=1. student_richting: R_ID= 1, richting=Web-Development

Comment: what's with last join.You are repeating a join there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining multiple tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15987321/3404097)

Comment: This is a faq. Google (variations of) 'stackoverflow' with your tags & title.. Re 'sample data', there are presumably 4 inputs & a desired output, and table defintions. Format tables using code format. Read & act on [mcve]. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following will fulfil your need.

```
SELECT S.S_Id Student_Id, S.Naam Student_Name, SV.vak, SR.richting
FROM Student_Info S 
INNER JOIN Student_Combi SC ON S.S_id  = SC.S_Id
INNER JOIN Student_Vak SV ON SC.V_Id = SV.V_Id
INNER JOIN student_richting SR ON SV.R_Id = SR.R_Id
```

--Example

```
CREATE TABLE #student_vak
(V_ID   INT,
 vak        NVARCHAR(256),
 R_ID   INT)

INSERT INTO #student_vak
SELECT '1', 'HTML','1'

CREATE TABLE #student_richting
(R_ID       INT,
richting    NVARCHAR(256)
)
INSERT INTO #student_richting
SELECT '1', 'Web-Development'

SELECT SV.vak, SR.richting
FROM #student_vak SV
INNER JOIN #student_richting SR ON SV.R_Id = SR.R_Id
```

Comment: Thank you. Are these the actual "names" I should use, because in the second case i get the error: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'SV'. Did you short SV for a table name or?

Comment: Means,In 2nd Query u r getting Error.? @mweb

Comment: The first answer gives me: #1054 - Unknown column 'SR.student_richting' in 'field list'. Changing the info into the second answer gives me: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'SV'

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. Replace SR.student_richting with SR.richting.

Comment: Edited the Answer. Check now. @mweb