# How to join 3 tables?

Tags: sql

```
select
    p.FirstName,
    e.ID_PERSON
from
    Persons p
    inner join Enrollment e on (p.ID = e.ID_PERSON )
    inner join Courses c on (c.ID = e.ID_COURSE )
```

This gives me the following error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(p.ID = e.ID_PERSON) inner join Courses c on(c.ID = e.ID_COURSE)'. (-3100)

Comment: You don't use parentheses in `JOIN` clauses. Remove them so your SQL has `inner join Enrollment e on p.ID = e.ID_PERSON inner join Courses c on c.ID = e.ID_COURSE`

Comment: This has already been answered here-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987321/joining-multiple-tables-in-sql.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message looks like an MS Access error message.  If so, that database has very arcane syntax conventions, even for `join`s.

You can try:

```
select p.FirstName, e.ID_PERSON
from (Persons as p inner join
      Enrollment as e
      on p.ID = e.ID_PERSON 
     ) inner join
     Courses as c
     on c.ID = e.ID_COURSE;
```

Comment: I found that you're No1 user, but strange thing. did you really ask nothing here? even one ??
For a greeting, I upvote you.

Comment: @DenisTurgenev . . . Oddly, I have generally found StackOverflow already answers pretty much all my question.  I like to return the favor.

Comment: Genius! don't worry. i am not kidding!

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(p.ID = e.ID_PERSON) inner join Courses c on(c.ID = e.ID_COURSE)'. (-3100)

Don't include parenthesis...This works at least on Sql Server

```
select
    p.FirstName,
    e.ID_PERSON
from
    Persons p
    inner join Enrollment e
    on p.ID = e.ID_PERSON
    inner join Courses c
    on c.ID = e.ID_COURSE
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks right. I would split the query into multiple lines so you can get a better idea of where the error is actually occuring:

```sql
SELECT p.FirstName, e.ID_PERSON
FROM Persons p
INNER JOIN Enrollment e
  ON p.ID = e.ID_PERSON
INNER JOIN Courses c
  ON c.ID = e.ID_COURSE
```