# SQL join based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to join two tables based on the condition.

Table1:

```
ID      Portfolio
3       Department
5       Laboratory
```

Table2:

```
DepartmentID   LaboratoryID
     3              5
```

How can I join ID from table 1 with DepartmentID and LaboratoryID with table 2?

I tried below and didn't work

```
INNER JOIN Table1 ON 
(SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Portfolio = 'Department') = 
Table2.DepartmentID AND
(SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Portfolio = 'Laboratory') =
Table2.LaboratoryID)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it's not clear what your desired results are, please add your expected results.

Comment: @Stu: I want to know how I can join these columns.

Comment: table1 join with table2 for two times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining multiple tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987321/joining-multiple-tables-in-sql)

Comment: You have sufficient rep and experience to know that "didn't work" and "don't get result" are not useful information and to know that good questions should provide DDL, sample data, and clearly defined goals. Posting a fragment of a syntactically incorrect query is not useful - esp. when you don't mention the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

..join table1 twice, once for departmentid and once for laboratoryid :

```
select dl.departmentid, d.portfolio as depname, dl.laboratoryid, l.portfolio as labname
from table2 as dl
join table1 as d on dl.departmentid = d.id
join table1 as l on dl.laboratoryid = l.id;
```

Comment: But I don't get result when I put two joins. Either of only one join returns result.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Table1.ID
     , Table1.Portfolio
     , department.DepartmentID
     , laboratory.LaboratoryID
FROM   Table1
 LEFT
  JOIN Table2 AS department
    ON department.DepartmentID = Table1.ID
   AND Table1.Portfolio = 'Department'
 LEFT
  JOIN Table2 AS laboratory
    ON laboratory.LaboratoryID = Table1.ID
   AND Table1.Portfolio = 'Laboratory'
;
```